# convert char to integer

Tags: c, char, int, output

I'm trying to input a series of numbers (i.e. `123456789`), and then having output it each one at a time (i.e. `1, 2, 3, ... , 9`). However, after the 9, which is `str[9]` onwards, the output value would be random numbers such as `-48, 32, 9, -112`. How do I make sure the output numbers stops at 9, since the last number I had input was 9?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100];
  int n,num[100];
  scanf("%s", str);
  for(n=0;n<100;n++)
    {
      num[n] = str[n] - '0';
      printf("%d\n", num[n]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: stop your loop when `str[n] == 0`

Comment: `n<100` --> `n<100 && str[n]`. also `str[8]` is `'9'`.

Comment: Wow, that was all it took. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The string you input from `scanf` might be less than 100 chars, use `strlen` to get its size:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = {0};
    int num[100];
    size_t len, n;
    scanf("%s", str);
    len = strlen(str);
    for(n=0;n<len;n++)
    {
        num[n] = str[n] - '0';
        printf("%d\n", num[n]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note you should use `int main(void)`, not `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to take length of you input string, Use **strlen(str)** , And store that value in one variable and up to string length rotate the loop. That's it:
- Here, I did :

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<string.h>
> int main()
> {
>  char str[100] = {};
>  int n = 0,count = 0,num[100] = {};
>  scanf(" %s", str);
>  count = strlen(str);
>  for(n = 0; n < count; n++) 
>  {
>    num[n] = str[n] - '0';
>    printf("%d\n", num[n]);  
>  } 
>  return 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare ascii value.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char str[100];
 int n,num[100]=0;
 scanf("%s", str);
 while(str[n]<58 && str[n]>47){
  num[n] = n*num[n]+str[n];
 n++; 
}
printf("%d\n", num[n]);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be processing the input once character at a time instead of as a string.  This would eliminate the need for the seemingly arbitrary 100 char limit.  You could validate that the character is a digit before printing, terminating the loop when the first non-digit it found.

```
#include <ctype.h>
char c;
scanf( "%c", c );
while (isdigit(c))
{
    printf("%c\n", c );
}
```